# Placeholder в несколько строк

Tags: html, javascript

Перерыл пол гугла - не понял как можно сделать placeholder в несколько строк у `<textarea>`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VescJ/ Не очень код?

Comment: если например, хочется написать в textarea то что в placeholder ? например "placeline" :) надо получше проверять input, ну и newline можно существенно упростить используя replace.

Comment: ну и аттрибут myholder - не стандартный, лучше используйте data-myholder. и обращайтесь к нему $element.data('myholder');

Comment: @Олег Б кстати, что за дурацкий способ ссылаться на $(this) вот таким образом ?

    $('textarea').eq(a)

Comment: @Олег Б - вот я поправил основные недочеты вашего кода, http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VescJ/3/

в общем, используйте var, используйте просто var $this=$(this); вместо той монстроидной конструкции, не используйте нестандарных элементов, лучше используйте data, старайтесь по поводу одного и того-же элемента делать поиск в dom всего один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312623/insert-line-break-inside-placeholder-attribute-of-a-textarea
- http://jsfiddle.net/pdXRx/5/

Comment: Сорри что лезу: opera next 16.0.1196.55, ни один пример не работает(

Comment: Ну собственно в первой ссылке об это и написано, а вторая это доказывает :] Так что да, оно не работает и не будет работать.

Answer (score 5):

Есть очень простой способ: сделать переводы строк при формировании html.

```
<textarea rows="5" placeholder="Первая строка
Вторая строка
Третья строка"></textarea>
```

[image: Пример многострочного placeholder]

Answer (score 2):

Многострочный placeholder, который работает во всех браузерах, включая Firefox.
К тому же очень легко настроить внешний вид.

У такого способа есть свои недостатки, но в большинстве случаев они будут не критичны.

[Пример на fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tropic/74na7vkh/)

```js
$(document).on('input', '#textArea', function () {
 
        if ($('#textArea').val()) {
            $('#placeholderDiv').hide();
        } else {
            $('#placeholderDiv').show();
        }
        
});
```

```css
#textAreaWrap {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}

#textArea {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    resize: vertical;
    background-color: transparent;
    /* When set background-color: transparent - Firefox  displays
    unpleasant textarea border. Set border style to fix it.*/
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
}

#placeholderDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 6px 13px;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="textAreaWrap">
    
    <textarea id="textArea"></textarea>

    <!-- Check here. If textarea has content -
         set for this div attribute style="display: none;" -->
    <div id="placeholderDiv">Multiline textarea<br>
                             placeholder<br>
                                          <br>
                             that works in Firefox
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  textarea::placeholder{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите более развернутый ответ.

Comment: Пример стилей для placeholder.